# Stream order from flow accumulation raster

Tags: grass-gis, hydrology, rivers, hydrology-toolset

I am looking to get Strahler Stream Order vector from a flow accumulation raster of a river network. I only find solutions with an elevation or direction raster.

Can I do this with GRASS?

Comment: I think most require flow direction. You can generate this from the DEM and then generate the order. Why are you restricted to performing this on flow accumulation alone?

Comment: Because I already have the stream network with the accumulation raster, but not the DEM associated and I need  use that stream network for other analysis.

Comment: looks like you can use the stream network (vector) on it's own if topologically correct to generate strahler order. https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/v.stream.order.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the GRASS addon `r.stream.order`. You can see an overview at [here](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R.stream.*_modules) and more details in the  [main page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/r.stream.order.html)

Comment: I already look this addon, but the problem is that require the direction raster and I only have the flow accumulation raster for my stream network. At least that there is some way to calculate the direction from accumulation.

Comment: You first run `r.watershed` to create the flow direction raster, then use that for `r.stream.order`.